# Update key-value pairs in an Array of Dictionaries without using for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have several dictionaries (NSDictionary) in an array (NSMutableArray).

All dictionaries have the same keys but different values.

Example:

```
({
    Price = 100;
    Quantity = 3;
},
{
    Price = 200;
    Quantity = 5;
})
```

Is there a way to update the value of a particular key in all dictionaries in one go without using for loop.

That is, is there a way to make Quantity=0 for all dictionaries in the array in one go?

**Edit:** I am looking for performance since I have a huge array of dictionaries, and I'm under the assumption that there may be faster way to do this than using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is your friend.

```
[dictionaryArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

}];
```

However,performance of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is much better when you are looping through  dictionaries.

Here is a good analysis of performance of loops in objective-c:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/high-performance-collection-looping-objective-c.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dictionaries are mutable, you can do `[array setValue:@0 forKey:@"Quantity"];`. This is using the Key-Value Coding `-setValue:forKey:` method. Normally, that would only set a property of the receiver, but for `NSArray`, it's documented to perform that method on each element:

> Invokes setValue:forKey: on each of the array's items using the specified value and key.

Mind you, any technique that anybody can provide is going to use a loop under the hood. The only thing you can do is have the framework do the looping for you.